# How can one find the general term of a series (basic algebra)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I know I'm getting a reputation for being bad at algebra, but I quite need the help. 
In this booklet (https://madasmaths.com/archive/maths_booklets/further_topics/various/series_summation_practice.pdf), page 23, how does the teacher convert from the function given to the sigma function. I am still working through it. 
The question states that:
$$f(n)=1\cdot[n^2] + 2[(n-1)^2] + 3[(n-2)^2] + 4[(n-3)^2] +\dots+ (n-1)\cdot (2^2) + n\cdot(1^2).$$
Determine a simplified expression of the sum of $f(n)$, giving the final answer in fully factorized form.

To generalize the question even further, how is one supposed to spot abstract patterns like that? My intuition is that there is some form of inspection, but even with inspection there must be some form of starting point.

Comment: Do you mean geometric series, arithmetic series, or both?

Comment: can you give us an example please?

Comment: The example is in the booklet, page 23. It's what I am currently stuck on :/

Comment: The booklet you link to is not even numbered, so to write "page 23" says  very little. Better, write down your exact question on the body of your post.

Comment: I apologise. I have added the question. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should not change the question after it has been answered.  If you have a new question, ask it in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative way (hopefully simpler) to manipulate the given sum.
The generic term of the sum is the product of two integers $j$ and $k^2$. Now note that $j+k=n+1$ so $j\cdot k^2=(n+1-k)\cdot k^2$ and we obtain
$$1\cdot n^2+2\cdot (n-1)^2+\dots +(n-1)\cdot 2^2+n\cdot 1^2=\sum_{k=1}^n(n+1-k)\cdot k^2\\=
(n+1)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n k^2-\sum_{k=1}^nk^3.$$
Then you should use the "known" formulas:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n (n + 1) (2 n + 1)}{6} \quad\mbox{and}\quad
\sum_{k=1}^n k^3=\frac{n^2 (n + 1)^2}{4}.$$

Comment: But sir, how did you get there? Did you do it by inspection? If so, where did you get such inspection from? Moreover, I want to point out that the subsequent operations of summing up the series I find trivial because I have been taught them. It's just following rules. I find first and second order differential equations easier because there is a stated logic behind them. Algebra does sometimes lead me astray. However, it is spotting the nth term of the series that I find difficult. I tried coming up with generalisations, but my attempts were futile. So, is it done by inspection?

Comment: Look at the general term of the sum, it is a product of two integers $j$ and $k^2$. Now note that $j+k=n+1$ so $j\cdot k^2=(n+1-k)\cdot k^2$.

Comment: This specific example makes sense sir. I also want to ask about the Maclaurin series, may you please answer that too?

Comment: It is better to ask a new question in a new thread. Then someone will answer for sure!

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n (n+1-r)r^2
&=\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{s=r}^n r^2\\
&=\sum_{s=1}^n\sum_{r=1}^s r^2\\
&=\sum_{s=1}^n\sum_{r=1}^s \binom r2+\binom {r+1}2\\
&=\sum_{s=1}^n\binom {s+1}3+\binom {s+2}3\\
&=\binom {n+2}4+\binom {n+3}4\\
&=\frac {(n+2)(n+1)n}{2\cdot 3\cdot 4}[(n-1)+(n+3)]\\
&=\color{red}{\frac {n(n+1)^2(n+2)}{12}}\end{align}$$